# Hi, I want to open a Popup model on button click in typescript chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8YbL.png)This shows error that we can not use import outside module. How can i import a modal on this button click.
Creating chrome extension in react 18 using typescript.
This is my Content script code.

```
import Popup from "../src/Modals/Authentication";
function init() {
    const injectElement = document.createElement("button");
    injectElement.className = "rustyZone-element";
    injectElement.innerHTML = "Icon";
    injectElement.onclick = function () {
        // const popup = window.require("../src/Modals/Authentication")
        console.log("here");
        const injectElementPopup = document.createElement("div");
        injectElementPopup.className = "popup-class";
        injectElementPopup.innerHTML = Popup;

    };


    document.querySelector(".theme-icon").appendChild(injectElement);
}
init();
```

Comment: did you add type="module" on script tag ?

Comment: Yes I did, but still same error